# Is there any way to format my logs in Cloud Function in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging 

class LoggingClass:

@staticmethod
def _get_logging_level(level):
    level = level.lower()

    if level == 'debug':
        logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    elif level == 'info':
        logging_level = logging.INFO
    elif level == 'warning':
        logging_level = logging.WARNING
    elif level == 'error':
        logging_level = logging.ERROR
    elif level == 'critical':
        logging_level = logging.CRITICAL

    # Default logging level
    else: logging_level = logging.INFO

    return logging_level

@staticmethod
def setup_logging(level='INFO', mode='formatted'):
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    client.get_default_handler()
    cloud_logger = logging.getLogger('CloudLogging')
    logging_level = LoggingClass._get_logging_level(level)
    cloud_logger.setLevel(logging_level)

    if mode == 'simple':
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    else:
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
                            '%(process)d - %(thread)d - %(asctime)s - '
                            '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        )
    chl = logging.StreamHandler()
    if cloud_logger.handlers:
        cloud_logger.handlers.pop()
    chl.setFormatter(formatter)
    cloud_logger.addHandler(chl)
    return cloud_logger


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cloud_logger = LoggingClass.setup_logging(level='INFO')
    cloud_logger.error("ok")
    cloud_logger.warning("ok1")
    cloud_logger.info("ok2")
```

The output I get on my Cloud Function log is:

```
12828 - 3444 - 2021-02-01 18:57:26,451 - CloudLogging - ERROR - ok
ok
12828 - 3444 - 2021-02-01 18:57:26,451 - CloudLogging - WARNING - ok1
ok1
12828 - 3444 - 2021-02-01 18:57:26,451 - CloudLogging - INFO - ok2
ok2
```

CAN SOMEBODY RECTIFY WHERE AM I GOING WRONG? Why the duplication? I only want the first line logs on Cloud Function in that format. If I do not use, google cloud logging, I see significant delay in the logs. However using google cloud logging, there's no delay but the duplication!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have at look at this article: [Python and Stackdriver Logging](https://medium.com/google-cloud/python-and-stackdriver-logging-2ade460c90e3)

From the best of my understanding you get such results because the logging happens asynchronously and in small batches (another thread behind the scene).

Comment: I read this. And I tried to use the custom one but even then it prints "hello"

Comment: Secondly, I get it it happends asynchronously but why the duplication of logs?